# Android sensor code example understanding

Tags: android, android-studio, sensors, shake

I'm new to android development and I have this code that make a shake event, what I do not understand is what Last_x is used for?

If I understand correctly last_x is detecting the last x-axis value of when the last shaking event happened. But how does it works, when last_x = x and x is event.values[0].

```
private float last_x;

public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    Sensor mySensor = event.sensor;

    if (mySensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
        float x = event.values[0]; //x value

            if (Math.abs(last_x - x) > 2) {
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(new LatLng(55.654929, 12.139613))
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ORANGE))
                        .title("Hey you moved the x axis on"));
            }
            last_x = x;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Every time when there is a change in X axis, We are taking the new x point in to float x; and transferring the same value to last_x for next time usage. This last_x is used to calculate the difference between the old one and current one. Once the calculation is completed, the last_x will be replaced with current x.

Comment: Also, for the code "Math.abs(last_x - x) > 2", the threshold is very arbitrary. The onSensorChanged function is called at different rates depending on your settings when registering the sensor, e.g. SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL/GAME/UI/FASTEST, etc.